# Java - If statement required to display the value as 0.00 instead of 0.0

Tags: java, if-statement, decimal

I created this code to display a certain output however the output is displayed with as so:

> First Class Parcel - Cost is £3.3
>   John Smith, 1 Downing Street, SQ13 9DD
>   Weight = 1.342kg.

This piece of code is the part of the output about(First Class Parcel - Cost is £3.3) However instead of displaying 3.3 I want to display 3.30.

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        double cost = 0.00;
            if (this.isFirstClass()){
                cost = 3.30;
                str = "First Class Parcel";
            } else {
                cost = 2.80;
                str = "Second Class Parcel"; 
            }
                return str + " - Cost is £" + cost + "\n" + super.toString() + "\n";
        }
```

Comment: So, format the value the way you want it.

Comment: Look into [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: By the way, you generally shouldn't use `double` for monetary amounts, because the values 3.30 and 2.80 cannot be represented exactly by a `double`.  You can look at http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/ to see what the actual value will be, and why.  For small amounts like this, it's unlikely to make a difference.  But for future use, you'll want to look into the `BigDecimal` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you :

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        double d= 23.2;
        System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
String.format( "%.2f", cost);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Worked, thank you kindly :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `DecimalFormat`. Something on the lines like following

```
    double cost = 3.30;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); 

    System.out.println("Cost is £" + df.format(cost) );
```